# what is the path of ANDROID environment variable?

Tags: android, windows

i get this error message on the command line after trying to invoke avd manager : 
"'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command". 
can anyone tell which path the ANDROID environment variable should point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the folder containing android.bat (tools folder) to the path.

See this for help.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Comment: i have multiple sdk folders from which one to choose? in my android folder i have folders : sdk, sdk1, sdk2, sdk3, sdk4, sdk5

Comment: Here's step by step procedure https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-beginners/a2HXKZKomL4